# Bundle Java program for Mac users with maven from GNU/Linux

Tags: java, macos, maven

I am trying to bundle a java program for Mac users. I first found [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) that explains how to do it with Ant, and then, I found [this](https://github.com/federkasten/appbundle-maven-plugin) that seems perfect for Maven.

So I added to my pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>sh.tak.appbundler</groupId>
    <artifactId>appbundle-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>xxx</mainClass>
        <iconFile>xxx</iconFile>
        <jrePath>???</jrePath>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>bundle</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

(I also found [this article](http://web.archive.org/web/20160716075200/http://blog.tsaplin.com/packaging-of-java-applications-for-mac-os-x-with-maven-on-linux-or-windows/) that explains some details about Mac bundles and why to use appbundler)

The only issue is that on every example I found, I see `<jrePath>xxx.jdk</jrePath>`. But I am running this under Ubuntu, so I only have the GNU/Linux jdk. Where can I find the Mac jdk ? On the [oracle website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), I can only find the dmg file. I extracted the dmg and got an hfs. I mounted the hfs and got a pkg. I extracted the pkg, and have now more file I don't know what to do with...

Comment: Java is cross platform and you should be able to run a JAR on either platform, so is your question how to install Java on a Mac?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the example(s) you are talking about?

Comment: @cricket_077 Yes, more or less. I am trying to bundle the jre along with the application. I found this practice to be recommended for Mac users on many websites. OrtomalaLokni, I edited the description to add the links.

Comment: Could you please update the link in the sentence:

"_I also found this article that explains some details about Mac bundles and why to use appbundler_", it seems to have changed. Thanks.

Comment: I think I found it. Hope it is the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are step by step what I did to do it with a test project on `Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS`.

In your case steps 1 to 3 will be done on your GNU/Linux env and the last one on Mac OS X.

#### 1. Download the `JRE`

As you only need the `JRE`, the easiest thing to do is:

1. To go to the [download area](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html),
2. Click on [`JRE DOWNLOAD`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html),
3. Choose the `tar.gz` version of the `JRE` for `Mac OS X` which is currently `jre-8u112-macosx-x64.tar.gz`.
4. Untar the content of the archive in the folder of your choice that we will call `${jre-folder}` (for example `/foo/bar/jre1.8.0_112.jre`).

#### 2. Create my test project

My typical maven project structure:

```
TestProject
└── src
|   └── main
|       └── java
|           └── my
|               └── pkg
|                   └── MyClass.java
└── pom.xml
```

My class `my.pkg.MyClass` which actually does an arbitrary task. Here, it simply dumps the system properties into a temporary file, just to be able to easily check that it has been called:

```
package my.pkg;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path path = Files.createTempFile("MyClass", "txt");
        try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path)) {
            System.getProperties()
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .forEach(
                    entry -> {
                        try {
                            writer.write(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue() + "\n");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                        }
                    }
                );
        }
    }
}
```

My `pom` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>TestProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>sh.tak.appbundler</groupId>
                <artifactId>appbundle-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>my.pkg.MyClass</mainClass>
                    <!--
                       For example
                    <jrePath>/foo/bar/jre1.8.0_112.jre</jrePath>
                    -->
                    <jrePath>${jre-folder}</jrePath>
                    <generateDiskImageFile>true</generateDiskImageFile>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>bundle</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

#### 3. Build my test project

Simply launch the command `mvn package appbundle:bundle` from the root of the directory `TestProject`.

This will build the **dmg file** in the `target` folder with the **`JRE` for `Mac OS X` included**, in this particular case it will be called `TestProject-0.1-SNAPSHOT.dmg`.

#### 4. Test my test project

On the target `Mac OS X`:

1. Double click on the **dmg file**, it will automatically mount the image,
2. Then you will be able to double click on `TestProject.app`, you will see an icon appear and quickly disappear as the test program is rather short
3. You can check that it worked properly by launching `cat $TMPDIR/MyClass*` from a terminal, you will then see the content of the temporary file that has been created by the test application.

---

#### 5. Add resources to the dmg file

To add resources to the generated **dmg file**, you can use `additionalResources` with a `fileSet`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>sh.tak.appbundler</groupId>
    <artifactId>appbundle-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        ...
        <additionalResources>
            <fileSet>
                <directory>/path/to/my/resources/folder</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.pdf</include>
                </includes>
            </fileSet>
        </additionalResources>
    </configuration>
    ...
</plugin>
```

This example will add all the `pdf` files from `/path/to/my/resources/folder` into the generated **dmg file**.

#### 6. Add resources to the app file

To add resources to the generated **app file**, you can use `additionalResources` with a `fileSet`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>sh.tak.appbundler</groupId>
    <artifactId>appbundle-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        ...
        <additionalBundledClasspathResources>
            <fileSet>
                <directory>/path/to/my/resources/folder</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.pdf</include>
                </includes>
            </fileSet>
        </additionalBundledClasspathResources>
    </configuration>
    ...
</plugin>
```

This example will add all the `pdf` files from `/path/to/my/resources/folder` to the generated **app file** into `/Contents/Java/lib`, they will be automatically included to the classpath of your application such that you will be able to access them easily.

Comment: Sounds promising ! Thanks. I can't test right now but I think that you fairly deserve the bounty. Very clear and very precise. Thanks !

Comment: Ok, in the end, my only problem was that on [this page](https://www.java.com/fr/download/manual.jsp) there is not the .tar.gz version of Mac jre... I successfully generated a dmg. Just need to try it somewhere.

Comment: Last question. How should I provide the files needed by my app (images, config...) ? I usually zip them along with my jar. Should I just zip the dmg with the files ?

Comment: I don't know it depends on your needs, do you want to include your resources into the app file?

Comment: Actually, I don't really mind. For Windows users, I have an exe file and the ressources packaged outside. I use Inno Setup to create an installer that will put all theses resources in the correct directory.

Comment: Actually I'd rather have them outside the app file I think.

Comment: Ok, fine then. As a Mac OS user, do you think that it's an expected packaging for a regular user ?

Comment: I would lie if I said yes, it should be in the dmg file and for this you should use `additionalResources` with a `fileSet`

Comment: I added an example that shows how to add resources to your dmg file

Comment: Oh man, I'm so grateful. Ok, so if I package the ressources within the dmg, how can I access it in the app ? Would the relative path from the parent of the Main.class be ok ?

Comment: if you need to be able to access from it from your app, you had better to have your resources in your app file

Comment: Yeah, but I need some of them to be edited or accessed from outside the app. Even if I could probably find a different way if it was totally needed.

Comment: You're right. Well, ok. I couldn't access a Mac yet, but anyway, you deserve your bounty. Thanks a lot for your time and efforts !

Comment: This was helpful. However, when I follow your example with my own code (yours works as presented), it "appears" that everything is created correctly, but when I double click on my app file, the icon appears, then disappears (it's a swing app, I am expecting a UI to come up).  Am I missing something?

Comment: You probably need to drag and drop the application into the Applications folder.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the `jrePath` tag is not necessary unless you want to include the jdk in the bundle. I build without it, and the application will use the default jdk. the `jrePath` tag is only used to bundle the jdk with the application. I didn't need to do that, so I just left it out.