# Making a Java application for Mac users

Tags: java, macos, maven

I succesfully generated a dmg file thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39193868/bundle-java-program-for-mac-users-with-maven-from-gnu-linux). My issue now is that when I open the .app file, the program starts and immediately stops.

1) On Mac, how can I get the java error if any?

2) I think that the error occurs because the .app cannot access the files that are within the dmg. The same answer indicates that I could add my files to the .app file. I can do that, but then, how am I supposed to access these files from my application? What would be the path I should use?

3) For GNU/Linux and Windows users, I currently have a .jar file that updates my application by updating the myapp.jar file and some other files. If everything is packaged into the myapp.jar file, how am I supposed to do that?

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have not tested the following but based on what’s described at [Bundle Java program for Mac users with maven from GNU/Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39193868/bundle-java-program-for-mac-users-with-maven-from-gnu-linux/40177180#40177180), the following are the steps I would try.

1. Open Terminal and `cd` to whatever directory `.app` is in.
2. Run `find . -name java`.

   That will return something like `foo/bar/jre1.8.0_112.jre/bin/java` I guess.
3. Run `find . -name myapp.jar` where `myapp.jar` is the name of the jar you made.

   That will return something like `foo/bar/myapp.jar`.
4. Run `foo/bar/jre1.8.0_112.jre/bin/java foo/bar/myapp.jar`.

If that runs, some error message will get emitted that should explain what else is not working.

Note that you can change files inside that `.app` directory; specifically, you can replace the jar file within the directory.

Comment: But if I am correct, when you create an app, you don't have the jar anymore, are you ? The jar is bundled inside the app, no ?

Comment: On MacOS, you know a `.app` is actually a directory, right? So you can examine the contents of the directory from bash in Terminal. And I don’t know what the actual end result is in the directory structure and contents that the mechanism http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39193868/bundle-java-program-for-mac-users-with-maven-from-gnu-linux produces, but I assume it must have the jar file still inside that `.app` directory somewhere. If it doesn’t then I’m not sure how else it’s cause java to load the necessary class files.

Comment: I didn't know that .app files where also directories... Never touched a Mac in my life ^^. Ok, Last question : can I edit/create files inside the .app file ? Can I update the .jar file for instance ? Please, put the answer in your answer. I will select it.

Comment: OK, yes you can make changes to the contents on an `.app` directory—the the last sentence I just now added to my answer.