# Deploying JavaFx for different OS

Tags: javafx, ubuntu-16.04

I' m using netbeans IDE for create JavaFx application on ubuntu.My question that can i deploy installer for **MAC Os** and **Windows OS** on ubuntu?

Comment: Maybe the [packager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/packager.html).

Answer (score 0):

For Mac OS you can look into [Bundle Java program for Mac users with maven from GNU/Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39193868/bundle-java-program-for-mac-users-with-maven-from-gnu-linux)

For Windows look into Inno setup.