# Javafx Desktop Application Deployment

Tags: javafx, deployment, installation, executable, desktop-application

I am trying to deploy a javafx desktop application. What are the executable files I need to create to cover as much as possible OS(windows/linux/Mac etc.) and how to create it? I want to package the JVM in the executable file so that the end user need not have to download any extra software.I am using netbeans 8.2 on windows 8.1 operating system.  Thanks.

Comment: If you want people to be able to answer your questions, you have to ask questions within the scope of this site and it needs to be clear what you are asking.

Comment: Read the manual on [Self-Contained Application Packaging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html)

Answer (score 0):

For Mac OS you can check out this link [Bundle Java program for Mac users with maven from GNU/Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39193868/bundle-java-program-for-mac-users-with-maven-from-gnu-linux)

And for Windows you can look into Inno setup for building a .exe